# What would be a good test case for this method?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am enrolled in a Software Testing course this semester and have started studying the first chapter. I am confused on this method and why it is considered flawed.
Integers are implemented using 16 bits on this computer executing this software, the lowest possible input value is -32768 and the highest is 32767.

```
/**
 * 
 * This is a example program in the book for software testing called
 * A practitioner's Guide to Software Test Design
 * I don't understand why the book says that the weakness of this program
 * is that the method will need to create a new memory slot for a larger
 * integer.  Why is that a problem?  The program doesn't crash.
 */
public class TestCase {

  //The book test these values and states that these are not successful test
  //cases.  Why is that?  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(testCase(bla(1),0));
    System.out.println(testCase(bla(42),0));
    System.out.println(testCase(bla(40000),1));
    System.out.println(testCase(bla(-64000),-2));
  }

  public static int bla(int arg){
    arg = arg - 1; // should be arg = arg + 1
    arg = arg/30000;
    return arg;
  }

  public static boolean testCase(int i, int test){
    return (i == test) ? true : false;      
  }

}
```

I have already asked my teacher about this problem, but I don't think that she knows exactly why this is wrong.

What would be a correct test case for this problem then?  More so I don't understand that if the problem is that a new memory slot needs to be allocated for another int in a 16 bit system why that is a problem.  Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: First things first, integer is 4 byte in java i.e. 32 bits.

Comment: This is true, but for this problem from the book it says to assume integers are implemented using 16 bits.

Comment: aaa wait.  Ok so that is why when I ran this program it didn't fail in eclipse. So when I entered 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295 into the program it doesn't run.  Ok I think I understand now.

Comment: great. good it worked.

Comment: A test compares the behaviour of something with the behaviour expected if the thing conformed to its specification. But you have not given us a specification, so we can not tell you how to test your method.

Comment: My professor says that there are 6 ways for this method can fail. I get confused here because anything below the min if integer or over the max will make this fail.  Clearly there is something more complicated to find here.

Comment: AL so my professors changed the problem a little and I know the answer to what she wanted me to do.  I'll post it here for the sake of completeness.  I am supposed to make two methods, one that does arg = arg + 1 and one that does arg =  arg - 1. Where arg is of a short datatype. Then compare the output of the methods the ones that do not match is where the program will fail.  So the program will fail when -32768, -30000, -29999, 29999, 30000, 32767 are used as arguments.